# Is there any Git hosting/server with IP ACL?

Tags: git, security, authentication

Most of the git hosting services and servers provide acl based on ssh keys. I'm wondering if there is any which provides also ip access restrictions per user.

Use case: I have a build/testing bot which I would like to grant read only access to the repository i'm testing. As part of the build process this server may need  access to other repositories(.e.g submodules) so that means we need to provide it a global key with access to all the repositories.

It seems to me that there is a great security risk that a developer with access on a small/less important repository could commit code which reveals the ssh key from the build server and then use it to get access to all the repositories. Nevertheless the ip restriction would enhance the security for regular users too acting as a 2nd factor authentication.

Comment: This question will almost certainly get closed in not too long, but some people will use down votes instead of close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem with your proposed security model is that build scripts are generally able to execute arbitrary code; as you point out, that could be exploited to extract the key for reading all of the repositories.

However, if that's the case, then the IP based access restriction won't help you.

A better model would be to separate checking out the code from building it. Check out the code on one host, and then build it on another, sandboxed host that only has access to that checked out code.

There are a number of ways you could architect this, so I won't go into all of them here, but one example would be that the master machine, which has access to the Git repositories, then scp's the code to the actual build machine. A firewall prevents any outgoing connections from the build machines; allowing only ssh access in from the master, which copies the files into place and initiates the build process.

There are a number of other variations you could do involving virtual machines, sandboxed containers, etc. But the fundamental idea is that if access to the Git repositories is considered privileged, and the build processes are untrusted, you don't ever allow the build processes to run in any environment in which they could get access to the Git repositories, or anything else that they shouldn't have access to.

Comment: You are right but after I put a bit more thought into this it seems to me that the only way to mitigate the risk is to ask the client (i.e whoever commits the code) to provide the environment variables (such the ssh keys to download the other repositories / dependencies) on each build. That way the build server will run / download only the assets that the client already has access to. The sandbox machine model is still vulnerable because the tests are supposed to run automatically so whatever runs there can be printed to the build log and inspected by the attacker.